# Indexing of XML files using Apache Lucene

Tags: java, xml, lucene

I need help regarding the approach which should be used for indexing almost 1000 XML files using Apache Lucene. Should I parse these XML files using SAX parser and then add required fields in Lucene document or should I marshal a Java object out of these XML's, store in in Hashmap and then iterate to get the fields and store them in Lucene index. Which approach should be used here, Would appreciate the help

Thanks
Rkalra